# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'split' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a Thymeleaf template with a Datatable (1.10.15).
I have this datatable defined:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#deviceEventTable').dataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        initComplete: function() {
            var api = this.api();
            var selected = localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ).split(',');
            selected.forEach(function(s) {
              api.row(s).select();
            })
          }
    });


    table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
          localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
        })

} );
```

But when I init the table I got this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'split' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `null` from `localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' )`

Try adding checks before doing the `split()`